# Getting contacts from on-premise company email using Teams Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

We're building a `Teams` extension using `React` and `Teams Toolkit`. After struggling with permissions in `Azure Portal` I am finally able to call the `Contacts.Read` endpoint using the `Graph API` without get barked at to log in and ask for permission each and every time.

I am logged into `Teams` using my work email, which I believe is hosted on-premise.

The call fails, claiming that "The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise." Here is the response:

```
  {
        "error": {
            "code": "MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI",
            "message": "The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise."
        }
    }
```

According to my admin, we may need to enable `Exchange` in order to get our work email contacts, and enabling `Exchange` is not free.

Is there a way to access the `Graph API` in some kind of sandbox mode? Or is there another workaround?

Comment: The Microsoft Graph Explorer is a tool that lets you make requests and see responses against the Microsoft Graph API in a "sandbox" kind of environment. You can use it to test and experiment with the API without making changes to your own tenant. However, please note that some operations might require admin consent.
You can access the Graph Explorer at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer. It allows you to sign in with your own account or use a demo account provided by Microsoft. Please note that this can only be used for testing purpose.